# Are there any alternative to this overload case in python with typing?

Tags: python, mypy

currently I am implementing a lot of subclasses that should implement a function, this is a minimal example of the current project.

In this case, I have a function that needs to call, to the login of a user, but depending of the implementation injected previously the application will use `UserUP` or `UserToken`

Because in `login_user` I have all data available for the two options, I set the params like follow.

```
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class User(Protocol):
    def login(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError


class UserUP(User):
    def login(self, user: str, password:str, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(user)
        print(password)


class UserToken(User):
    def login(self, token:str, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(token)


def login_user(user: User) -> None:
    user.login(user="user", password="password", token="Token")

login_user(UserUP())
login_user(UserToken())
```

The problem is that when I run `mypy` I get errors like the following:

```
app.py:10: error: Signature of "login" incompatible with supertype "User"  [override]
app.py:10: note:      Superclass:
app.py:10: note:          def login(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None
app.py:10: note:      Subclass:
app.py:10: note:          def login(self, user: str, password: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None
app.py:16: error: Signature of "login" incompatible with supertype "User"  [override]
app.py:16: note:      Superclass:
app.py:16: note:          def login(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None
app.py:16: note:      Subclass:
app.py:16: note:          def login(self, token: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None
```

Of course, the signature is incompatible, but which alternatives do I have to implement things like this?

Comment: Please edit your title so it summarizes your question

Comment: `user`, `password`, and `token` are all positional arguments. I would try making them keyword-only arguments (add an unnamed parameter with an asterisk, like  `, *, `). Along with that, it doesn't make sense to have two classes `UserUP` and `UserToken`.  I would use a single class with `login_username_password` and `login_token` as methods. Alternatively, you could take the username/password or token in the constructor instead of an overloaded method.

Comment: The another classes are given by another teams and injected in the flow, this is a reduced example about the real use case, but I am looking for any way of typing a function given a object with a particular function but several args. And if I add *, I get the same mypy problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use keyword_only marker in all signatures and describe all possible parameter in `User.login`

You need to expose which possible keywords can be used, and which type, in the main function.

```py
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable


@runtime_checkable
class User(Protocol):
    def login(self, *, user: str, password: str, token: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError


class UserUP(User):
    def login(self, *, user: str, password: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(user)
        print(password)


class UserToken(User):
    def login(self, *, token: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        print(token)


def login_user(user: User) -> None:
    user.login(user="user", password="password", token="Token")


login_user(UserUP())
login_user(UserToken())
```

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

## Protocol leads to implementation

SUTerliakov suggested another implementation in the comment section: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=358f3ceba80b1d8141e49d223e25495a

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, runtime_checkable, ParamSpec


_P = ParamSpec('_P')


@runtime_checkable
class User(Protocol[_P]):
    def login(self, *args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    

class UserUP(User[str, str]):
    def login(self, user: str, password: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print(user)
        print(password)


class UserToken(User[str]):
    def login(self, token: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        print(token)


def login_user(user: User[Any]) -> None:
    user.login(user="user", password="password")

login_user(UserUP())
login_user(UserToken())
```

This solution generate a valid `mypy` report:

```py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

There is two caveats with this implementation:

1. You don't need to update the protocol to pass `mypy`, which means that you can create new implementation that require specific arguments without `mypy` telling you that the protocol requires it:

With the following code, you have a valid `mypy` check and yet, a crash because `token` is required by the `UserToken.login` method.

```py
def login_user(user: User) -> None:
    user.login(user="user", password="password")
```

mypy result: `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

Run result:

```
TypeError: UserToken.login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

2. You can't trust the protocol. Static type checking won't warns you that some subclasses of `User` need specific arguments.

## What is the behavior of this answer solution:

The protocol protect further implementation. If the protocol doesn't state that a specific parameter need to be fulfilled to match any protocol implementation, you **can't** define an implementation requiring this parameter.

Let's remove the `token` argument in our `login_user` like previously:

```py
def login_user(user: User) -> None:
    user.login(user="user", password="password")
```

mypy result:

```
file.py:23: error: Missing named argument "token" for "login" of "User"  [call-arg]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: I downvote, because this suggests a very problematic way: `User` is not really abstract of some kind any more, because you'll need to inject all new arguments into the original protocol to define a few more implementations (login backends). If you want to add UserGoogleSSO, UserFacebookToken, User2FACustom, etc., you'll have to rewrite `User` protocol every time.

Comment: @SUTerliakov No, just if you want to be explicit on the expected types of specific keyword. And Yes, if you don't have a default implementation for `User.login` you need to rewrite the protocol implementation, but it's not because of the type or my answer, but by design without default implementation. If you want to discuss more about that, maybe we can discuss in [chat] ! :)

Comment: No, I mean that third class with `def login(self, *, foo: str, **kwargs) -> None` will require you to add `foo: str` to `User.login` definition as well, and it's an opposite of abstract backend definition. Since the OP doesn't need that parameters keyword-only, I'd say that generic solution is better (see [this playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=358f3ceba80b1d8141e49d223e25495a), I'll post is as answer a bit later)

Comment: @SUTerliakov ok I see your point, but for me, your are understanding this the wrong way. The protocol doesn't addapt to new implementation, it's new implementation who need to adapt to protocol. If the protocol doesn't allow a `foo` parameter, you can't create a login asking for this, period. You need to follow the protocol. If you want to support new implementation, then you need to change the protocol accordingly, which is great. I'll update my answer to show you the behavior I'm speaking about.

Comment: @SUTerliakov updated. What do you think?

Comment: Okay, that also makes sense, great!